# webサーバ移行に際して運用平行期間のwordpressの記事投稿について

Tags: wordpress, サーバー管理

他社のサーバに移行する際に、DNSなどの問題で両サーバの運用平行期間があると思うのですが、
Wordpressを用いて運営しているウェブサイトにおいて、その平行期間における新規記事の投稿は
どのようにすべきでしょうか？

両方のサーバに同時に新規記事の作成・公開はできるのでしょうか？

私の考えとしてはDBサーバを新サーバの方に統合して、記事データはそちらから取ってくるようにしようと思っているのですが、画像や動画ファイルはどのように配置すべきでしょうか？
サーバの移行に際して、ドメイン名の変更はおこなわないので、各々のサーバに保存されている画像や動画ファイルを取ってくるにはどう指定すれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

サービス無停止での切り替えが必要ということでしょうか？

無停止が必要であればスルーしてください。

グローバルIPの変更を伴うサーバー移行では私の経験では以下のようにしてました。

- 移行前にDNSのTTLを短く設定(5分とか30分とか60分)しておく
- 新サーバーを起動
- 旧サーバーでhttp status 503を返す
- DNSを新サーバーへ設定
- 旧サーバーのアクセスログを監視しアクセスが収束したら旧サーバー停止
- DNSのTTLを戻しておく

---

無理矢理な(一般的でないかもしれない)方法で設定も邪魔くさいですが旧サーバーから新サーバーへProxyしてしまうとか…

Comment: サービス無停止が必要なんです・・・
回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: DNSのTTLがあまり下げられないとかよっぽどな状況でなければこの方法ても基本的にダウンタイムはなくほぼ問題は起きないはずですけどね…………まぁ画像とかが気になるのであれば元からS3等に画像が向くようにしてくなりでも安心できますが。